# How to disable Prime Faces datatable bindSelectionKeyEvents

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

[image]I am trying to edit the row of datatable using row expansion, but the `<p:input>` is not accepting any `space`, `new line` in IE 11. Other browsers working fine. Its only IE11. After JS debugging, I found that when ever enter something in the input, it goes to

```
 bindSelectionKeyEvents: function () {
    var a = this;
    this.getFocusableTbody().on("focus", function (b) {
        if (!a.mousedownOnRow) {
            a.focusedRow = a.tbody.children("tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-selectable.ui-state-highlight").eq(0);
            if (a.focusedRow.length == 0) {
                a.focusedRow = a.tbody.children("tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-selectable").eq(0)
            }
            a.highlightFocusedRow();
            if (a.cfg.scrollable) {
                PrimeFaces.scrollInView(a.scrollBody, a.focusedRow)
            }
        }
    }).on("blur", function () {
        if (a.focusedRow) {
            a.unhighlightFocusedRow();
            a.focusedRow = null
        }
    }).on("keydown", function (f) {
        var d = $.ui.keyCode
                , b = f.which;
        if ($(f.target).is(":input") && a.cfg.editable) {
            return
        }
        if (a.focusedRow) {
            switch (b) {
                case d.UP:
                    var g = a.focusedRow.prev("tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-selectable");
                    if (g.length) {
                        a.unhighlightFocusedRow();
                        a.focusedRow = g;
                        a.highlightFocusedRow();
                        if (a.cfg.scrollable) {
                            PrimeFaces.scrollInView(a.scrollBody, a.focusedRow)
                        }
                    }
                    f.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case d.DOWN:
                    var c = a.focusedRow.next("tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-selectable");
                    if (c.length) {
                        a.unhighlightFocusedRow();
                        a.focusedRow = c;
                        a.highlightFocusedRow();
                        if (a.cfg.scrollable) {
                            PrimeFaces.scrollInView(a.scrollBody, a.focusedRow)
                        }
                    }
                    f.preventDefault();
                    break;
                case d.ENTER:
                case d.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                case d.SPACE:
                    f.target = a.focusedRow.children().eq(0).get(0);
                    a.onRowClick(f, a.focusedRow.get(0));
                    f.preventDefault();
                    break;
                default:
                    break
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I don't need any keyboard shortcut for my project. So as a simple solution I wanna disable it.

I have tried with:

```
          $(document).ready(function () {      
                        PF('tablePartner').bindSelectionKeyEvents = null;
                      });
```

Comment: Tried the latest PF?

Comment: This is 6.1. Don't know why its behaving like this in IE11.

Comment: running in compatibility mode?

Comment: Can't  run with compatibility mode, regulated by company. other jQuery and JS function working fine.But its working with Edge.

Comment: I did not say you should run in compatibility mode, I said running in compatibility mose could be a cause

Comment: Sorry for my comment. I see. but how is other jquery component and primeface component working then I wonder. :(

Comment: If you don't run in compatibility mode I have no clue. Don't have IE at hand so cannot test (even of there was a [mcve]. Maybe try PF 6.2 snapshot from git

Comment: I will try with 6.2. thanks for the suggestions.